# Ring of dual numbers 2.8 Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme. For any point $x \in X$, we define the Zariski tangent space $T_x$ to $X$ at $x$ to be the dual of the $k(x)$-vector space $\mathfrak m_x/\mathfrak m_x^2$. Now assume that $X$ is a scheme over a field $k$, and let $k[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2$ be the ring of dual numbers over $k$. Show that to give a $k$-morphism of $\text{Spec} (k[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2)$ to $X$ is equivalent to giving a point $x \in X$, rational over $k$ (i.e., such that $k(x) =k$), and an element of $T_x$.

$\text{Spec} (k[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2)$ is a $k$-scheme in the above Problem 2.8 Hartshorne. In order to solve the problem, do we have to assume that the $k$-scheme structure on it is induced by natural ring homomorphism from $k$ to $k[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2$ sending an element of the field $k$ to it's equivalence class modulo $\varepsilon^2$?

Comment: Please state the problem, rather than just give a reference to it.

Comment: For $k$ a field a $k$-scheme $X$ means that for each $U\subset X$ open we are given compatible homomorphisms $k\to O_X(U)$. Then a $k$-scheme morphism $X\to Y$ is defined locally by some homomorphisms $O_Y(V)\to O_X(U)$ which must be compatible with the given embeddings: $k\to O_Y(V)\to O_X(U)=k\to O_X(U)$. For affine schemes it suffices to check the case $U=X,V=Y$. This is the generalization of the idea that varieties over a field have ring of regular functions (and field of rational functions) that are $k$-algebras.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. However I still don't have an answer for my question.

Comment: As per the request of Peter, I have added the question from Hartshorne.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're asking? Certainly Hartshorne means to give $\text{Spec}(k[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2))$ its natural $k$-scheme structure induced by the standard inclusion $k\to k[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)$. By "do we have to assume...", do you mean "is there some *other* $k$-scheme structure on $\text{Spec}(k[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2))$, such that if we work with that $k$-scheme structure, the result is false?"

Comment: @user474986 the $k$-scheme structure on $\operatorname{Spec}(k[\varepsilon]/\varepsilon^2)$ you mention is definitely the intended $k$-scheme structure, and though I haven't checked this I'd wager that the problem is not true in general without this choice of $k$-scheme structure.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved the problem using the assumption and it works out fine.